# Flyway fails when One procedure calls another, in DB2

Tags: db2, flyway

The following bit of SQL, fails with flyway v5.1.3 against DB2 LUW 10.5, but it works when executed directly in DB2 using a client.

The error message:

> " DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-440, SQLSTATE=42884,
>   SQLERRMC=TEST_STATUS;PROCEDURE, DRIVER=4.19.26"

Definitely a problem with flyway. Does anyone know a workaround or fix?

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE TEST_STATUS
  (
    IN a INTEGER,
    INOUT b INTEGER,
    INOUT c INTEGER,
    INOUT d INTEGER
  )
  BEGIN


  END;


CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE TEST_STATUS_MAIN
  (
    IN a    INTEGER,
    IN b INTEGER,
    IN c    INTEGER,
    OUT d BIGINT
  )
  BEGIN
    DECLARe e INTEGER DEFAULT 0;

    CALL TEST_STATUS(a, b, c, e);


  END;
```

Comment: May be a function path issue, so Check if explicitly qualifying TEST_STATUS with a schema name both in the declaration and in the invocation makes a difference...  Also: don't mix IN and INOUT types for the same ordinal paramter between the call and the definition.

Answer (score 0):

This may happen if `CURRENT SCHEMA` is not in the `CURRENT PATH` list for the session.
Let's say,
`VALUES CURRENT SCHEMA` returns `SCHEMA1`
`VALUES CURRENT PATH` returns `"SYSIBM","SYSFUN","SYSPROC","SYSIBMADM","SCHEMA2"`.
The routine `TEST_STATUS` is created in the `SCHEMA1` schema, and it's being tried to be found in the `"SYSIBM","SYSFUN","SYSPROC","SYSIBMADM","SCHEMA2"` list, upon an attempt to create `TEST_STATUS_MAIN`.